# Heat equation and Fourier series

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fourier-series, boundary-value-problem, heat-equation

I am trying to solve the following boundary value problem involving the heat equation:
$$
\frac{\partial{u}}{\partial{t}} - \frac{1}{4} \frac{\partial^2{u}}{\partial{x}^2} = 0,\;\; t > 0 \text{ and } 0 < x < 1, \\
u(0,t) = u(1,t) = 0,\;\; t > 0, \\
u(x,0) = \sin{(2 \pi x)} - \frac{1}{3} \sin{(4 \pi x)}, \;\; 0 < x < 1.
$$
I used separation of variables $u(x,t) = X(x) T(t)$ and got down to $u(x,t) = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} b_k e^{-\frac{1}{4} (k \pi)^2 t} \sin{(k \pi x)}$ for some $b_k$.

My question is, how do I use the initial condition $u(x, 0)$ and finish this problem off by finding $b_k$? I assume I would have to use Fourier series on sine, but I'm not sure how to proceed with this. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The formula you have for $u(x,t)$ is not correct.

Comment: I seem to be getting $X(x) = A \sin{(k \pi x)}$ and $T(t) = Be^{-\frac{1}{4} (k \pi)^2}$ for k = 1, 2, 3, .. after using separation of variables. What should the correct values be for $X(x)$ and $T(t)$?

Comment: You are supposed to have a sequence $(b_k)$ instead of a single $b$.

Comment: Thank you, have edited the post. I am still not sure how to find $b_k$, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Buy uniqueness of Fourier series expansions the expression for $u(x,0)$ gives $b_2=1,b_4=-\frac 1 3$ and $b_k=0$ for all other $k$.